# Vectorised Kernel using Jax

Tags: python, jax

I am trying to compute the following [kernel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nPZr.png) using `grad` and `jacfwd` in jax:

where [k(x1,x1',x2,x2')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahclC.png) is a singly differentiable function in each of its variables ( Specifically I am using a squared exponential function, where the input is a vector *x* = (x1,x2) and *x'* = (x1',x2') ).

Currently I am trying

```
import jax,numpy as jnp
from jax import jacfwd, grad
from jax.numpy import exp
from jaxtyping import Float64
from jax import vmap

#some test data

x = jnp.array([[-0.89999998,  0.89999998,  0.        ],
       [-0.89999998,  0.89999998,  1.        ],
       [-0.80000001, -0.89999998,  0.        ],
       [-0.80000001, -0.89999998,  1.        ]]).T

y = jnp.array([[-0.89999998,  0.89999998,  0.        ],
       [-0.89999998,  0.89999998,  1.        ],
       [-0.80000001, -0.89999998,  0.        ],
       [-0.80000001, -0.89999998,  1.        ]]).T

SE = lambda x1, y1,x2,y2, V=1 , L=1 : exp(
                -0.5/L * ( (x1-y1)**2 + (x2-y2)**2 )
                )
        
      
SEVars = [x[0],y[0],x[1],y[1]]

DivsPhi = jnp.array(jax.jacobian((vmap(grad(SE,[0,2]))),[1,3])(*SEVars))
```

which works, but in this case gives a horrendous 2x2x4x4 jnp array object, whereas I would like a 8x8 object. The code does 4x the amount of necessary computation due to permutations of the variables passing into the function. Is there a better way of achieving the desired kernel? Thanks.

Comment: Can you say more about what output you are hoping to attain? (i.e. what shape were you hoping it would be?) Also, please double-check your example code: it leads to errors when I attempt to execute it

Comment: Thanks, I've just fixed these, the code should run now

Comment: I'm sorry, I just don't understand how the 2x2 kernel you mention in the first paragraph can be related to the 8x8 output you mention in the last sentence. Also, is it intentional that you do not use all rows of `x` and `y`?